# How to Connect SQL server from client to Server PC using Connection string in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to connect SQL Server from Client PC using the below-mentioned string, but it Is showing error as "**Login failed for user 'sa'**"

Tried string:

```
public static string connString = @"Data Source=(eg.IP)10.0.255.255,1433; Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=InventoryProjects;User Id=sa;Password=password";
```

I have provided IP , userid and passward are correct.

Happening:
DB is not connected from Client PC.

Expectation:
But it should connect as I expected.

Can Anyone Please guiding me to proceed Further, because I am not very much familiar in C# and SQL

Comment: Just provide correct User Id and Password.

Comment: Warning. Don't post real password or user id on here. I don't think that you want "(eg.IP)" in the connection string

Answer (score 0):

Points that spring to mind:

- `(eg.IP)` should be removed from the connection string
- Is IP address correct - may not be if it is dynamic?
- Is the user id and password correct - use of `sa` user id may not be allowed?

Check - if you are able to run Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to connect to the SQL database and check the connection string.